# Filter Dynamic Partitioning in Apache Hive

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, hive, hadoop2

Trying to create a Hive table but due to the folder structure it's going to take hours just to partition.

Below is an example of what I am currently using to create the table, but it would be really helpful if I could filter the partioning.

In the below I need every child_company, just one year, every month, and just one type of report.

Is there any way to do something like `set hcat.dynamic.partitioning.custom.pattern = '${child_company}/year=${2016}/${month}/report=${inventory}';` When partitioning to avoid the need to read through all folders (> 300k)?

`Language: Hive`

`Version: 1.2`

`Interface: Quobole`

```
use my_database;

set hcat.dynamic.partitioning.custom.pattern = '${child_company}/${year}/${month}/${report}';

drop table if exists table_1;

create external table table_1
(
    Date_Date    string,
    Product   string,
    Quantity    int,
    Cost  int
)
partitioned by
(
child_company string,
year int,
month int,
report string
)

row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\n'
location 's3://mycompany-myreports/parent/partner_company-12345';

alter table table_1 recover partitions;
show partitions table_1;
```

Comment: Not clear. (1) what do you mean by "filter the partitioning."? (2) what do you mean by "due to the folder structure it's going to take hours just to partition"?

Comment: Yes it's going to take hours just to partition currently two hours in. I was wondering if it was possible to choose to only read through relevant folders        In pig you can do something like folder1/2016/Month=* to only search through the folders your looking for

Comment: Man, I have no idea what are you talking about. Are you asking how to create a partitioned table? Are you familiar with `alter table ... add partition (...) location ...)`?